# Sitecore 8 : ControllerCreationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I'm using sitecore 8.1 which apparently supports Areas as well. To get POC going, I downloaded sitecore81areas project from below:

https://github.com/LonghornTaco/Sc81Areas

And added a simple hello world controller.

However, I'm getting the error below when trying to access the sitecore item:

```
[ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.]
[ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller: 'Sc81Areas.Web.Areas.Site1.Controllers.Hello'. 
The context item is: '/sitecore/content/Site1'. 
The current route url is: '{*pathInfo}'. This is the default Sitecore route which is set up in the 'InitializeRoutes' processor of the 'initialize' pipeline. ]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +202
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.GetController() +23
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute() +43
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +134
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +216
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +259
   ASP._Page_Areas_Site1_Views_Shared_Site1DefaultLayout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\sitecore\sitecore81\Website\Areas\Site1\Views\Shared\Site1DefaultLayout.cshtml:19
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +221
[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Areas/Site1/Views/Shared/Site1DefaultLayout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
```

I disabled the default route configurations:

```
//routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "Default",
            //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //);
```

Also

1. added Area on Layout.
2. Removed the default routes under Areas Registeration.
3. Added mvcarea on site nodes

---

Still the error persists.  I'm bit confused what exactly what could be the root cause (may be configuration setting or DI).

**Not sure if my controller needs to inherit from specific sitecore controller.**

Your help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I wanted to share my code but it's quiet big. Basically I downloaded the SC81Areas project from repo below and added the hello controller:

https://github.com/LonghornTaco/Sc81Areas

Comment: Did you specify the `mvcArea` attribute on your `site` node in config? Have a read through this [blog post](http://citizensitecore.com/2015/10/26/mvc-areas-in-sitecore-8-1-a-step-by-step-guide/) for a step-by-step guide

Comment: It wasn't there, now I've added it and still throws the same error. Does my controller need to inherit from normal Controller or something else?

Comment: I've updated my question above as well with full stack trace and my findings.

Comment: It's just a regular controller, no inheritance required. Did you add the `AreaRegistration` class to your Areas folder with the correct `AreaName` string defined also?

Comment: Does your controller have an emtpy constructor only? Otherwise, do you have dependency injection setup correctly?

Comment: I had a non empty constructor which I've now removed. But still throwing the same error. Really surprised, what could be causing this issue.

Comment: @Chris van de Steeg, I updated my question with more details now.

Comment: Do you just have "Sc81Areas.Web.Areas.Site1.Controllers.Hello" in the field Controller on your rendering? If so, try either the whole type name with assembly name(eg Sc81Areas.Web.Areas.Site1.Controllers.HelloController, Sc81Areas.Web) or just "Hello"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message with the same stack trace. My problem was the name of the controller in my controller rendering. I wrote it with suffix "Controller" and that was wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you say that you have disabled the default router configuration thus I think you should register a router that you access via controller.
example : youdomain.com/example

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Example",
            url: "Home/Example",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Example" }
        );

        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);
    }
```

Please let me know if its useful.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work either. Not really sure if it's related to routing.

Comment: Do you have Home item like '/sitecore/content/Home' ?

Comment: Yep. sitecore/content/home/welocome. Where welcome has presentation detail which includes one controller rendering. This control rendering is causing the headache.

Comment: I had missed the important line(ControllerCreationException) on stack trace, I've added it now.